# Do you think that it is polite to ask some potential research directions?

Tags: research-process

I'm a young researcher in the field of optimal control on Partial Differential Equations. Recently, I reached out to some well-established researchers in my field to inquire about potential significant research questions, but unfortunately, I didn't receive any responses. Do you think it wasn't appropriate to ask?

Comment: Establishing good collaborations vs. one-way help seems like a better direction. Can you work with others at your current university?

Comment: You are basically asking random people to do your advisor's job.

Comment: @Dawn, Thank you for your answer. Currently, no one at my university is conducting research in this field.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post (I removed your second question)

Comment: @MATAKA Bluntly, that's kind of a "you" problem, not a "them" problem. You can move to an institution where people do research in the area you want to do research, or change your area of research. The level of support you need is not something likely to be provided by someone at another institution, they have their own students at their institution to supervise.

Comment: Also, what's a PDE?

Comment: @AdamPřenosil The word "basically" here is reducing a ~5-year professional relationship of guidance and mentoring to a ~1-hour response to an email. If this is your idea of an advisor's job, your students shouldn't bother mentioning your name in their thesis.

Comment: @PatrickNicodemus It's pretty obvious that what I meant was "answering such questions is part of your advisor's job", not "answering such questions is the sum total of your advisor's job".

Comment: Why don't you read through proceedings of a recent top conference in your area. These days papers are easily available online, especially on Arxiv. Finding open research questions in any area is never a problem. There are thousands of questions which needs answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, the solution to your problem: go to a conference, or to a workshop, and discuss in person, or have a look at what is "novel" and draw your own conclusions. No one knows better than you which significant research question **may fit** you.

Second: no, it was not appropriate to ask such a question, surely not if it was a cold email, but not even if you have a connection to the experts you contacted it. Why? because the question is quick to ask, but to answer it properly it requires an enormous amount of time. And the asker should spend 99% of that amount of time, not the answerer.

It takes an extreme amount of time to write and give out ideas, even second-hand ideas, this is basically what you are asking to the experts.

But do not worry, no one will remember you for having sent such an email: if an email is not interesting, it is rapidly forgotten (if, on the other hand, you start sending follow-up emails, or even an email where you say you are sorry for the first email, then sure you will be remembered, as a spammer or similar).

Step into the shoes of an expert on a certain field.

Let's assume the said expert is in a very good mood and they are very open. Receiving an email like yours, such an expert would think "let's check the profile of the asker". If it takes more than 10 seconds to find an arbitrarily vague association of yours with the topic, then your email is ignored.

Then the expert starts drafting an email, rapidly getting to the point "oh my gosh, there is so much to say about the potential new direction topic A/B/C", then they start to shorten the email, then after 20 minutes they think "I will complete this email later". Then your email is forgotten.

If said expert is in a normal mood, they will think "I will reply politely later" and they will forget it.

If said expert is in a bad mood, they will not think anything. They will skip the email and it will be forgotten forever.

To the last question: "prolific paper writing or gaining citations from other researchers" none of them.
Bureaucratic systems care about that. And funding bodies care about them, so experienced researchers care for them only as long as it goes hand in hand with a succesful track of getting grants.

If you have a high number of citations or a lot of papers, and you did not win any grants, it will be even counter-productive. Do not mix "potential causes" and "consequences". A succesful researcher probably has a lot of papers/citations, but a lot of papers/citations does not make a succesful researcher.

Comment: Maybe not a relevant comment, but I would expect asking such questions in the field of pure math is absolutely appropriate.

Comment: @Mihail thanks. Different worlds, different conventions ... the PDE world is close to the engineering domain, therefore my answer relates to this.